# Sumifs and multiple "all" criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a table that is like this - starting in cell `A1`:

| Color | Size | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | S | 45 |
| Green | M | 21 |
| Blue | L | 25 |
| Red | L | 20 |
| Green | M | 41 |
| Blue | S | 19 |

I'm trying to set up a formula that will return the total number Sold based on two selections - Color and Size. I have my selections in a drop-down list, and I have this formula that returns if my selections are any combination of the available selections

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=A10)\*(B2:B7=B10)\*C2:C7)
```

My goal is to have a selection with a drop-down list where I can select any combination of colors and sizes and it will output the total sold, but the list needs to also include All as option for BOTH Colors and Sizes.

```
=IF(AND(A10="All",B10="All"),SUM(C2:C7),SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=A10)\*(B2:B7=B10)\*C2:C7))
```

I tried this, where `A10` is my selected Color, and `B10` is my selected Size, and this works but only if I'm looking for the sum of all colors AND all sizes, otherwise it returns for the individual selections.

I'm looking for something that will let me choose any combination of selections, including `All`.

| Color | Size | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All | L | Total |
| Red | All | Total |

How can I write something that will sum up, for example, the total sold of all the colors that are size L only, or all of the reds regardless of size?

Comment: [`SUMIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula in `G2`:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7, A2:A7, IF(E2="ALL", "<>", E2), B2:B7, IF(E3="ALL", "<>", E3))
```

Here is the output for `ALL` cases, you can check any other combination:
[image: excel output]

You can use `SUM` or `SUMPRODUCT` as you tried as follow:

```
=SUM(C2:C7 * (A2:A7=IF(E2="ALL", A2:A7, E2)) * (B2:B7=IF(E3="ALL", B2:B7, E3)))
```

The advantage of using `SUM` instead of `SUMIF` is that you can use arrays instead of ranges because `SUMIFS` is a [RACON function](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions).